# Issue creating external tables from sql server to hadoop using polybase

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sql-server-2016, hortonworks-data-platform, polybase

We have recently installed Polybase in SQL Server. We are trying to use Hortonworks to get data. I am facing below issue while creating a external table.

```
Msg 105019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
EXTERNAL TABLE access failed due to internal error: 'Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_IsDirExist:  
Error [End of File Exception between local host is: "xxxxx"; destination host is: "xxxxx":1111; :  
java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException] occurred while accessing external file.'
```

I tried changing the `core-site.xml` file in SQL Server polybase location by uncommenting the Kerberos option which is now giving me the below error:

```
Msg 105019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
EXTERNAL TABLE access failed due to internal error: 'Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_Connect: 
Error [Unable to instantiate LoginClass] occurred while accessing external file.'
```

I suspect it might be with creating database scoped credentials.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL HadoopUser3
WITH IDENTITY = '<user>', Secret = '<Passw0rd>';  
go
```

Can someone help me understand the issue I'm having with the Identity and Secret. Is it related to Hadoop credentials? What kind of secret do we have to give?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

In your core-site.xml file try setting hadoop.security.authentication to lower case "kerberos".  Also, make sure you have added polybase.kerberos.realm and polybase.kerberos.kdchost

Make sure your data source created uses the correct LOCATION= to your HDFS cluster.  Make sure that is the IP address:Port and not the name of the server itself

Check the external table and ensure you have the right path to the cluster physical file itself.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This issue is resolved.